iwlwifi WRT: Invalid buffer destination in Ubuntu 24.04
A caveat
I have very little experience with Ubuntu and all the technicalities that come with it, so if there is missing information, I apologize in advance. Please ask in the comments and I will provide the missing information.
The problem
Recently, I installed a Ubuntu (Ubuntu 24.04.1) alongside my Windows operating system. Something strange happens when I close my laptop while it is on, or put it in sleep mode when hitting WIN+L. My laptop gets very hot, as if it is running a very heavy simulation in the background, even when I haven't opened anything on my laptop. This completely drains the battery, within an hour or so, from 100% even when no applications are running. Then, when I open it again, I sometimes see the following error message.

After opening and unlocking my laptop it stops running or computing whatever it is trying to do in the background. In the error messages, there is also something about the audio. Sometimes, after unlocking my laptop from sleep mode the only audio output I get is Dummy output. I have no idea if the above error message has anything to do with it, but I expect it does.
When I press Win+L when I run Windows, this issue is not apparent. Hence I have the idea that the issue really is on the Ubuntu part.
What I've tried

Changing the battery settings to "power save mode" or something of the like has no effect.
I looked on Stack Exchange, with no helpful questions. Other people on this site with this error message seem to not being able to boot at all. Apart from draining my battery (within < 1 or 2 hrs.) and sometimes the audio not working, the system runs completely fine.

